# MySQL: LIMIT 2,-1

Tags: mysql

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 1,-1";
```

Why I get an error report:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 2,-1
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1' at line 1

Comment: Are you saying that the first query was successful, but the second one fails?

Comment: Because of the -1, that is not supported. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to read all the rows from  the table except for the first row.

Comment: many documents I found said I should use LIMIT 1,-1. But -1 is causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
> ```

so in your case

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615";
```

Comment: but I found lots of documents from the web said if you set the second argument to -1, this means every row until the end of table will be picked. for example, if a table has 10 rows i want all of them except the first row, use LIMIT 1,-1

Comment: for me its more like an undocumented feature, i would recomend to stay on the documented features so your apllication remains scalable, IF you really what to use limit -1 then youll have to create a procedure/fn pass the limit as a parameter and use there limit @param and it should work with negative valueas. at least was working in  MySQL CE 5.5

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT clause is used in the SELECT statement to constrain the number of rows in a result set. The LIMIT clause accepts one or two arguments. The values of both arguments must be zero or positive integer constants.

since you use negative(-1) number and hence that error is shown.

Comment: but I found lots of documents from the web said if you set the second argument to -1, this means every row until the end of table will be picked. for example, if a table has 10 rows i want all of them except the first row, use LIMIT 1,-1